# How to make Firefox install langpack in its installation directory

Tags: windows, firefox

I want to configure a portable version of Firefox so that if I run it from another computer it will already have multi-language configuration setup (e.g. English + German); that way I won't have to install the xpi all over again.

Edit: to prevent misleading term "portable version of Firefox" note that I *don't* use Portableapps firefox, see my comment

Comment: Use portable firefox?

Comment: no, I simply take already installed folder of regular firefox

Comment: There is another folder used by Firefox named C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ where we can find the langpack *.xpi file added to firefox

Comment: @HocineDJEMAI ask stated I want it portable in its install directory not user profile.

Comment: I tried Firefox profile manager, but no result at this stage, [try it if you want](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles#w_starting-the-profile-manager). I think that the XPI file is stored in the profile directory, so with this , you can change the directory of your profile...

Answer (score 0):

Through filemon I found that firefox check existence of distribution\extensions in installation directory for existing addons. I put all of languages xpi into it. It works!

Not every addons can be installed this way though, some need to be extracted and placed in subdirectory inside distribution\bundles such as "language switcher" addon.

Note if those folder not exist just create it.